# Dealing with Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin Without CORS header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So I've got a simple getJSON() function:

```
            $.getJSON(apiURL, function(data) {
                 console.log('success');
                if (data.results.length > 0) {
                    $(song).find('source').attr('src', data.results[0].previewUrl);
                    song.play();
                }
                else {
                    console.log('No match found for track information specified.');
                }
            });
```

apiURL is an itunes API url, defined like this:

```
            var apiURL =" https://itunes.apple.com/search" +
                "?term=" + artist + "+" + album + "+" + title +·
                "&media=music&entity=musicTrack&callback=?";
```

I'm getting the classic Origin localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. I've dug for some answers on this, and they usually boil down to either using $.ajax and setting the dataType to 'jsonp', or using .getJSON and supplying a 'callback=?' parameter to the URL, which I've tried above. Neither of those seem to be working, and I've heard rumblings that they may be outdated. What is the most current, up to date advise on dealing with this problem? Besides collecting the data on the server.

Comment: without a cors header, not possible without using a server-side proxy, unless the remote api supports JSONP.

Comment: Is it possible to add a CORS header using jQuery? Also, the iTunes API appears to support JSONP, discussing the 'callback=?' parameter in its documentation, but I still get that error....

Comment: No, cors headers must be added by the server.

Comment: so $.support.cors = true won't work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a space at the beginning of your api url... once I removed that, the call went through:

http://jsfiddle.net/UU8tT/

```
var apiURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search" +
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the full `.ajax` method, rather than the `.getJSON` shorthand method:

```
var terms = ["Halestorm"];
terms.forEach(function (val, i, arr) {
    terms[i] = encodeURIComponent(val);
});
$.ajax({
    "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/search",
    "dataType": "jsonp",
    "data": {
        "term": terms.join('+'),
        "media": "music",
        "entity": "musicTrack"
    },
    "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, message) {
        console.log(message);
    },
    "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The above works for me in the browser console (while on stackoverflow). It also works on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xYthU/

Answer (score 1):

Browser will request server with OPTIONS method. Server has to response following headers to support CORS.

1. [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header) : Accept
2. [Access-Control-Allow-Methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#http-access-control-allow-methods) : *
3. [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#http-access-control-allow-origin) : *

If we request https://itunes.apple.com/search URL with OPTIONS method. It responses with error that not Supported.

Screenshot: https://blog.gaurangjadia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/itunes.apple_.com_.png